# Cypress Retries global configuration doesnt work

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, cypress-fail-fast

I have a problem with Retries in cypress.
I am usisng the fail-fast pluging also and this work perfect.
I have added in my cypress.config.ts configuration the retries option as global configuration as explained in the official documentation

[image]

all works fantastic, the html reports, the fail fast and so on, but not the retries, no idea why. I have review the official doc like one hundred times and also the fail fast doc just in case this is doing something with the retries but doesn't say to much.

when an error fails on run mode, even if it is configured for 2 retries it directly show in the log the fail fast and thats it, skip the rest without any retries.

[image]

[image]

NO retries at all :(

If you need more information about it I can send it, but according to the doc with the global configuration should be enough and also the fail fast plugin says:

[image]

it doesnt says anything elase about that something must be done with retries

UPDATE: The retries and different Attempts works fine but in Open mode only. Also I have seen that maybe is a problem because of the HTML report that only is generated in run mode.
Do I have to configure something else for retries when I also have implemented the HTML report?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Please describe expected outcome. Your last image says "after it's last retry" which implies you are getting retries on the failing test (although I can't see any retries in the other screenshots). Do you expect **not to fail fast?** If so, why do you have that library installed?

Comment: The spected result is basically what is shown is the log is not the right think, the answer below shows the expected result, but no idea why in my case doesnt try to retry when fails

Comment: there are two retries modes as shown in the screenshots, for one works but not for the other. It is explained in the question

Answer (score 4):

I made a simple test with this library [cypress-fail-fast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-fast) + retries set to 2 (both modes).

I behaves as I would expect, the first failing test retries 2 times, and the second test does not execute as expected because of the fail-fast configuration.

**test**

```js
describe('template spec', () => {

  it('fails test 1', () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(false)
  })  
  
  it('fails test 2', () => {
    expect(true).to.eq(false)
  })
})
```

**config**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
    openMode: 2,
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("cypress-fail-fast/plugin")(on, config);
      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

**support**

```js
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'
import "cypress-fail-fast";
```

---

**run mode**

```js
  Running:  spec.cy.js                                                                      (1 of 1)


  template spec
    (Attempt 1 of 3) passes
    (Attempt 2 of 3) passes
    1) passes
[fail-fast] Failed tests: 1/1
[fail-fast] Enabling skip mode


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) template spec
       passes:
     AssertionError: expected true to equal false
      at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js:3:20)

[fail-fast] Stopping Cypress runner due to a previous failure
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response the problem I think is due to I also have the mochawesome reporter and doesn't work because of that, if I remove the reporter it works. It is the last version of cypress and the cypress mochawesome reporter configured as it is explained in the official doc. Thanks a lot in advance